# At login screen, a progress bar logs me in without asking for password

Tags: login, password, security

first time here for asking a question :)

Everything is in the title : the issue happens when I'm at the login screen after booting my laptop, at the screen where I have to choose the account I want to log in ( I just have a single one actually). If I touch nothing, a little progress bar at the bottom of the selection box of the account starts and when it reaches the end of the box my session opens automatically without asking for the password. I looked for an option to avoid this issue ( because I don't really want ubuntu to open my session without asking the password) but I didn't find it. 
May I ask for help on this matter ? I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and the option for automatic login on user settings is unchecked, in case.